# Custom Build Configurations with Unity and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[I'm using versions 2017 of both Unity and Visual Studio, but I don't think that bears on this problem because the same issue existed in Visual Studio 2015 and Unity 5.5]

I have created a Build Configuration (Staging) via VisualStudio/Build/Configuration Manager/Active Solution Configurations/[new]

I have then created a publish profile for my WCF Service Application that pairs the Staging build configuration to a Web.Staging.config transform file.

The problem is that whenever Unity syncs up the solution file it removes this build configuration which breaks this publish profile and results in the Web.Debug.config transformation being used rather than Web.Staging.config.

So, my question is, how do I get Unity to leave this build configuration in the .sln file?